# Why does the box layout need a width attribute in CSS3?

Tags: css, layout

This is my code...

```
.box {
   display:-webkit-box;
 }
.item {
     -webkit-box-flex: 1;
     width:1%; //this value can be set to any value 
}
```

What is the meaning of the width attribute?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the Flexbox is to be dynamic, you should not need to set the width at all, that is the function of the `flex` property (which sizes each item relative to the items around it). There is a good article explaining all the features and functions of Flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). If you could provide a specific example of what you're trying to do then I could provide a more specific answer.

Comment: like this demo:demo ,if set 'a' tag width = 1%，the first line of the first can's aligned with the next line,I set it width = 0.00001% it can align

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the header, you don't need to set a width for your item when using flex. There are plenty of examples on the MDN. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-box-flex

By setting a width, you can control the minimum amount of space your .item will occupy in the parent element. But keep in mind no matter what you set the width to the items will not exceed the width of the parent divided by the number of items. So if you have 5 boxes in a container, the width of those boxes will not exceed 1/5th the width of the container.

I found a good video on using flex here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7EIAgfkhmg

Comment: like this demo:[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjMvZB) ,if set 'a' tag width = 1%，the first line of the first can's  aligned with the next line,I set it width = 0.00001% it can align  @DylanB